# Spring Security Oauth2 all urls are permitted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I would like to make some urls of my api public. But once I configure one single url, all my api become exposed without authorization.

Below my configure method of ResourceServerConfiguration class :

```
 @Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http
     .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/api/books","/api/plainOffers","/api/offers","/api/public/*").permitAll();
}
```

ResourceServer configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends    ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/books").permitAll();   
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/plainOffers").permitAll(); 
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/offers").permitAll();  
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/public/*").permitAll();    
      //http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
}
}
```

Authorization server :

```
@CrossOrigin
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig 
    extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Value("${api.oauth.tokenTimeout:3600}")
private int expiration;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
    .withClient("api")
    .secret("secret")
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
    .scopes("read", "write")
    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource");
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution for this? I am having same problem now. "Once I configure one single url, all my api become exposed without authorization or If I tweak for restriction it restrict all."

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to add the required restricions on other urls :

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/books","/api/plainOffers","/api/offers","/api/public/*").permitAll();
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but all endpoints became protected.                                  {
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}

Comment: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/forgottenPassword").permitAll();
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();`
this is working for me

Comment: Thank you Mohamed for the suggestion but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that if you have provided resource_id = api then remove /api and add urls like this ("/books","/plainOffers","/offers","/public/*") in rules.

Then it will work.